# Prevent Prettier formating arrow functions to multiple lines

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

When I write arrow functions in Vue.js using vscode i get an unexpected formating.

I wish to change the settings for Prettier when auto formating arrow functions in vscode.

**Expected:**

```
<input type="file" @change="(event) => { files = event.target.files; }" accept=".csv" />
```

**Acceptable:**

```
<input 
    type="file"
    @change="(event) => {files = event.target.files;}"
    accept=".csv" 
/>
```

**Actual:**

```
<input
    type="file"
    @change="
        (event) => {
            files = event.target.files;
        }
    "
    accept=".csv"
/>
```

Comment: This is not unexpected. Brackets aren't supposed to be formatted in one line, and even if they were, prettier isn't configurable that much. You just need to keep the amount of inline code in templates to a minimum, it's a bad practice any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found this feature has already been requested:
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4125

Changes to prettier were made (https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/6685) and released in prettier 2.0 back in 2020.
(https://prettier.io/blog/2020/03/21/2.0.0.html#improved-method-chain-breaking-heuristic-6685httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull6685-by-mmkalhttpsgithubcommmkal)

But looking at example you provided it is still not working great apparently :/

If it were any option in prettier to configure this behaviour it would've been in here:
https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html
But I haven't found anything that would help your case.

It seems to me the only thing you can do right now is to use

```
<!-- prettier-ignore -->
```

..before your line. You can read more about prettier ignore in html here:
https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#html

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer! <3

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here are the braces in the arrow function's body. If you're calling a single function in the body, you can simply do something like this:

```html
<button @click="(event) => doSomething(event)">Do something</button>

<!-- In Vue, you can also use this shorter syntax -->
<button @click="doSomething($event)">Do something</button>
```

In order to omit the braces, you need to return a single **expression** from the arrow function (check the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#description) for more information). [This article](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/expressions) explains pretty nicely how an expression is defined. The key takeaway is this:

> An expression is a snippet of code that evaluates to a value

Since variable assignment is an expression, you can just omit the braces (Prettier will add parentheses around the arrow function's body to make it clearer that it's a single thing). Prettier treats this differently and should render it on the same line, provided you're not exceeding your `printWidth`. Here are some examples with default Prettier settings, except for `printWidth` set to 120:

```html
<!-- Without braces (Prettier will add the parentheses) -->
<button @click="() => (someVariable = 'New value')">Assign a value to a variable</button>
<button @click="() => (true ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse())">Ternary operator</button>

<!-- Braces -->
<button
  @click="
    () => {
      someVariable = 'New value';
    }
  "
>
  Assign a value to a variable
</button>
<button
  @click="
    () => {
      true ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
    }
  "
>
  Ternary operator
</button>
```

### NOTE

The examples are just to illustrate how Prettier handles things. In Vue, you could actually just do `@click="someVariable = 'New value'"`, but in certain other frameworks you might need the full arrow function. Adapt to your framework as needed, but the behavior of Prettier should be similar.